# How can I duplicate or template from a GitHub repo and all of its submodules?

Tags: github

**DISCLAIMER:** I am not asking about forking or cloning. Duplicating (or templating) better describes what I am interested in accomplishing.

I have a common structure I like to use for my web apps. It involves a parent repo with several submodules. Let's call this a template.

I would like to be able to run a script that sets up all the repos and GitHub remotes for this template. I believe I know how I would write one myself. However, I wanted to see if such a solution already exists in some form in GitHub or a commonly used third-party tool. Does it?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-a-template-repository

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis this handles submodules? How does it determine the naming?